# What is the meaning of "error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)[8]' [-fpermissive]"?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum {ROW = 7, COLUMN = 8};

void show(int matrix[][COLUMN], int, int);

int main (){

    int horizontal = 0;
    int vertical = 5;
    int goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN] = {
                            {5, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0},
                            {0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1},
                            {4, 3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0},
                            {3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3},
                            {0, 5, 2, 0, 1, 1, 5, 1},
                            {2, 1, 6, 1, 6, 0, 2, 1},
                            {0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2}
                        };

    show(goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN], 1, 1);
    return 0;
}

void show(int matrix[][COLUMN], int x, int y){
    if(y >= COLUMN)
        cout << "[error: column index is beyond array limit]" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[" << matrix[x][y] << "]" << endl;
}
```

> The error is pointing to the function call 'show(goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN], 1, 1);' inside main. As a beginner I don't see any syntactical errors on that statement. Can somebody help?

Comment: `goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN]` refers to a single `int` (except it accesses the array out of bounds) and the function expects a 2-dimensional array - what is unclear?

Comment: `show` takes an `int [][]` but when you call `goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN]` you are indexing into the array which produces a single `int`. I assume you just meant `show(goldCoin, 1, 1)`

Comment: Thank's CoryKramer. I didn't know that.

Comment: As a side note the `goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN]` expression is reading out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calling `show(goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN], 1, 1);`, you are passing an `int` as first argument, not 2D array, as you probably wanted to.

I believe that you meant to do `show(goldCoin, 1, 1);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong way to pass in the argument. Pass in the array name identifier without the brackets:

```
show(goldCoin, 1, 1);
```

The expression `goldCoin[ROW][COLUMN]` represents one single value of type `int` in your 2D array. So you are passing `int` value in place of a `int (*)[]` value which is what the function expects. In this case this is actually reading out of bounds as there is no element with coordinates of  `[7][8]` represented with the `goldCoin[7][8]` because arrays are zero indexed.
Only in function declaration / definition the signature is:

```
void show(int matrix[][COLUMN], int, int);
```

Don't confuse the two.